# C++ std::vector iterator acting strange, won't allow incrementation

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, segmentation-fault

I'm attempting to use an `std::vector` in c++, specifically one of type `std::string`. However, the iterator is acting strangely when I attempt to insert elements into the `std::vector` and print them out.
The following code simply prints "Segmentation Fault":

```
std::vector<std::string> request;
auto it = request.begin();
request.insert(it, "foo");
request.insert(++it, "bar");
std::cout << request.front() + "\n";
```

The code also prints "Segmentation Fault" when I leave the iterator as is, i.e. if I do not try to increment it. If I comment out the line inserting "bar" into the code, i.e. without the `it` increment (`++it`), the code prints "foo". In addition, I can add "bar" using `request.begin()` or `request.end()` and it prints the right thing ("bar" or "foo" respectively). I'm asking this here because this behavior does not match up with the behavior displayed in the tutorial for `std::vector.insert()` given on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/), nor does it seem to match with any other examples on line, and I can't seem to figure out why it prints "Segmentation Fault" which I would assume would occur if you were to try to print a non-existing element, or at least that's what happened when I tested this theory on an empty vector.

Comment: After `insert` don't trust that `it` is still valid.

Comment: The tutorial you quote specifically comments _"// `it` no longer valid, get a new one:"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `it` is not required to be a valid iterator after

```
request.insert(it, "foo");
```

Hence, using `++it` in the next line, as

```
request.insert(++it, "bar");
```

is cause for undefined behavior.

You may use

```
it = request.insert(it, "foo");
request.insert(++it, "bar");
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't really understand what it was saying about that in the tutorial. That's weird and annoying but you gotta roll with the punches in programming sometimes.